# How to read and change body of a HTTP request?

Tags: java, http

I want to perform a REST operation on a request that gets generated for a user. I am trying to read the contents of the request body using this:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
String info =null;
try
        {
            reader = httpRequest.getReader();
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            e1.getMessage();
        }
```

I keep getting this exception:

```
     <b>exception</b>
            <pre>java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.getReader(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

It is on the getReader line. After this I want to do something like:

```
try
        {
            while((data =reader.readLine()) != null){
                LOGGER.debug("Line read from data is: "+ info);
                buffer.append(data);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e1)
        {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I cant get around that Exception. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `httpRequest` a HTTPServletRequest? Try adding a `catch ( UndeclaredThrowableException e ) { System.err.println( e.getCause().toString() ); }` to get the cause (see [UndeclaredThrowableException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html).

Comment: @Kenney Yes it is a HTTPServletRequest. It prints out the same exception text which I have posted above.

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you sure you have the `.getCause()` part?

Comment: I think getReader also throws an IllegalStateException which is not a sublcass of IOException.  http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getReader--

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your service reference (the RESTful service you're connecting to) is throwing an exception that your program isn't ready for nor understands. Or at least that's how I understand the docs on UndeclaredThrowableException.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/UndeclaredThrowableException.html

Comment: I was able to remove that error by doing this:  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpRequest.getInputStream()));   but it doesnt read the request if I have the while loop which I have posted in my code above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes. Use a DataInputStream and readFully (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readFully(byte[])) instead of a loop -- . Also, your LOGGER call is using an 'info' variable that seems to never be declared or assigned when what I think you want to be using is your 'data' variable.

Comment: on second thought you'll still need to loop, but you'll break out of it when you catch a EOF exception

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, it is info variable, not data. There is JSON being sent from client, so I don't think there should be an EOF exception?

Comment: Without more info I really can't test and help you that way. But I brought up info because it appears you are logging your read using info and then appending data to your buffer; is that your intention? I ask because that won't log what I think you want if info isn't assigned the same data that you read in. As far as the reader is concerned the end of the binary data that makes up the body of the request (which is what is returned by getInputStream) is the EOF. If I'm wrong someone correct me. Have you tried using a new DataInputStream(httpRequest.getInputStream()) instead of a BufferedReader?